# List of commonly occurring infinite sequences?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, reference-request

I'm looking for an online list of commonly occurring convergent infinite sequence, such as

- $n^a$ (converges to $0$ if $a < 0$, to $1$ if $a = 0$, and to $\infty$ if $a > 0$)
- $\sqrt[n]{n}$ (converges to $1$)
- $\sqrt[n]{n!}$ (converges to $\infty$)
- $(1 + \frac{x}{n})^n$ (converges to $e^x$)

For comparison, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions) is a list of commonly occurring Maclaurin series, and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Rules_for_basic_functions) is a list of commonly occurring derivatives. I'm looking for a similar list, only for sequences.

Comment: Apologies that this doesn’t directly answer your question, but instead of learning which series’ converge and when they do so, it is more beneficial to understand how to test individual series for convergence/divergence. There are some basic series  that are worth learning (such as geometric, p-series etc) but just a list of converging series probably isn’t as useful. Again apologies I couldn’t find a list with the convergence of certain series.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: Thanks, but it's important for me that it be publicly available online, so I can refer to it with a link.

Answer (score -2):

Consider $a_n=\frac{n}{\ln n\cdot \pi(n)}$. As usual $\pi(n)$ is the number of primes not exceeding $n$. It is known that $a_n\rightarrow 1$ and this fact is known as the [Prime number theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem)

Comment: These downvotes are not deserved, especially with no justification.

Comment: Why this is downvoted? It is a common sequence converging to $1$.